# Should I use a singleton class to manage a socket connection in my iOS5 application?

Tags: sockets, ios5, singleton

I'm making a multi-device iPhone app where the app needs to maintain a socket/NSStream connection with a server.

Various classes need to communicate with the server. I'm thinking of making a singleton class that maintains a connection (and reestablishes dropped connections) and having that app send out NSNotifications that drive the activity in the objects that need to communicate with the server.

The alternative, I suppose, would be to have a class that creates a connection and have that object instantiated by the various classes that need the internet connection. Then I suppose I'd have multiple socket connections going at once.

Logically, in my mind, either one of these would work. Any advice on best practices? What's the normal way for an app to maintain a socket connection as long as the app is running, while having the input stream drive activity throughout the application?